# How to fetch the records from identity tables in asp.net zero

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to fetch the records from identity tables(e.g. `AspNetUsers`, `AspNetRoles`) and I am using ASP.Net boilerplate framework.

I have created repositories for identity table using `IRepository` interface like:

```
private readonly IRepository<User,long> _userRepository;
private readonly IRepository<Role> _roleRepository;

public AccountController(IRepository<User,long> userRepository,
        IRepository<Role> roleRepository)
{
    _userRepository = userRepository;
    _roleRepository = roleRepository;
}
```

Then, I used these repositories to fetch the records using `GetAll()` method:

```
var roles =_roleRepository.GetAll().Where(u => u.TenantId == tenant.Id);
```

I am getting zero records from `AspNetRoles` table but there are some records in database. So, my first question is whether we can create and use repositories for identity tables?

I have also used manager methods like `GetUsersInOrganizationunit()` but it is also giving the same result (i.e. no records found).

```
OrganizationUnit usersInOrganization = new OrganizationUnit();
usersInOrganization.TenantId = tenant.Id;
var users = await_userManager.GetUsersInOrganizationUnit(usersInOrganization);
```

So, is there any better solution than above?

Comment: You'd have to show us the repository code really, otherwise we have no way to tell what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to wrap using of repository by UnitOfWork. Something like this:

```
    private readonly IUnitOfWorkManager _unitOfWorkManager;
    private readonly IRepository<User,long> _userRepository;
    private readonly IRepository<Role> _roleRepository;

    public AccountController(IUnitOfWorkManager unitOfWorkManager,
        IRepository<User,long> userRepository,
        IRepository<Role> roleRepository)
    {
        _unitOfWorkManager = unitOfWorkManager;
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _roleRepository = roleRepository;
    }

    public override async Task YourMethod() {
        using (_unitOfWorkManager.Current.SetTenantId(tenant.Id)) {
                 var roles =_roleRepository.GetAll();
                 var users =_userRepository.GetAll();
             }
    }
```